# Private SSH Key regex failing

Tags: regex, ssh-keys

I am working on a regex to validate Private SSH Keys. See [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/17iXRK/5)
I have written 8 test cases and one of them fails, which I am not able to figure out. Click on "Functions" Menu > "Unit tests(8)" sub menu

```
// regex

^-----BEGIN (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519) PRIVATE KEY-----(\s|\S)*-----END (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519) PRIVATE KEY-----\n$
```

```
// This is a valid SSH key without the type (RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519) which can be optional
// But this fails with above regex
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCSwwggkoAgEAAoICAQDdwAdrjscEeh1v
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks

Comment: I even tried getting help from ChatGPT and it was able to fix the above  single test case but failed with others

Comment: Why would you expect it _not_ to fail? You haven't made the alternation optional, and even if you did, your regex expects two spaces between `BEGIN` and `PRIVATE`.

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to use a capturing group for the validation, so that e.g. you detect the invalid 'BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY' / 'END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY' mismatched beginning and ending strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^-----BEGIN(?: (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519))? PRIVATE KEY-----\s*(\S[\s\S]*?)\s*-----END(?: (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519))? PRIVATE KEY-----\n$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/17iXRK/6).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `-----BEGIN` - a literal text
- `(?: (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519))?` - an optional sequence of a space and then a `RSA`, `OPENSSH` or `ED25519` substring
- `PRIVATE KEY-----` - a literal text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\S[\s\S]*?)` - Group 1: a non-whitespace char and then zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `-----END` - a literal text
- `(?: (?:RSA|OPENSSH|ED25519))?` - an optional sequence of a space and then a `RSA`, `OPENSSH` or `ED25519` substring
- `PRIVATE KEY-----` - a literal text
- `\n` - a newline
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^-----BEGIN (?:RSA |OPENSSH |ED25519 )?PRIVATE KEY-----\n.*\n-----END (?:RSA |OPENSSH |ED25519 )?PRIVATE KEY-----$
```

[image: test screenshot]

*.If you want to match the whole string and use a group to get the content between begin and end, replace `\n.*\n` with `\n(.*)\n`:
[image]